# MATLAB - Plotting a smooth volume from 3D scatter plot data

Tags: matlab, volume, surface

So I have data in the form [x y z intensity] that I plot on a scatter3 figure with xyz axes. The colour of the data is used to dictate the intensity value. Problem is, using a scatter plot means the data points show up as discrete points. What I need, is a smooth shape - so I guess I need some kind of interpolation between the points?

I've tried using trisurf, but the problem with this one is that it interpolates between points that it shouldn't. So where I should have 'gaps' in my surface, it joins up the edges instead so it fills in the gaps. See the attached pics for clarification.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

The code I use is as below (the commented out scatter3 is what does the scatter plot, the rest does the trisurf):

```
% Read in data
dataM = csvread('3dDispersion.csv');

% scatter3(dataM(:,1), dataM(:,2), dataM(:,3), 5, dataM(:,4),'filled');

% Plot
hold on;
x = dataM(:,1);
y = dataM(:,2);
freq = dataM(:,3);
tri = delaunay(x,y);
h = trisurf(tri, x, y, freq);

% Make it pretty
% view(-45,30);
view(3);
axis vis3d;
lighting phong;
shading interp;
```

[image: The scatter plot]

[image: The trisurf plot]

Comment: I am not sure if you can actually do that. Hope you find an answer.

Comment: Have you tried [alpha-shapes](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28851-alpha-shapes)?

Comment: @knedlsepp I have not tried that. I'm not overly optimistic, because I believe the trisurf function also uses Delaunay triangulation and that might be the thing that isn't working - but since I actually have no idea if that's true or not, I'll give your suggestion a try!

Comment: Upload the `3dDispersion.csv` somewhere.

Comment: I've been struggling with the same issue. Matlab does not seem to be able to do this properly.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `boundary` function in Matlab. This will apply a mesh similar to shrinkwrap over your points. In order to reduce the "gap closers", you will want to increase the "shrink factor".

Try `K = boundary(X,Y,Z,0.9)`

Where X, Y & Z are the vectors of your data points

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/boundary.html

You can then use `trimesh` or related surface plotting functions depending on how you want to display it.